# Конструктор копирования c++

Tags: классы, c++

В каких случаях используется конструктор копирования?! Интересуют как и самые обычные, так и очень редкие случаи. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](http://demin.ws/blog/russian/2009/03/15/constructor-call-in-cpp/) есть хороший пример, который показывает, какие конструкторы когда вызываются. Вариантов не много, поэтому экзотических случаев не будет. Правда, иногда компилятор может соптимизировать. Но это уже детали. Сам пример скопирую сюда, про запас.

```
#include <iostream>

class T {
public:
  T() { std::cout << "T()" << std::endl; }
  T(int) { std::cout << "T(int)" << std::endl; }
  T(int, int) { std::cout << "T(int, int)" << std::endl; }
  T(const T&) { std::cout << "T(const T&)" << std::endl; }
  void operator=(const T&) 
    { std::cout << "operator=(const T&)" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "T t1           : "; T t1;
  std::cout << "T t2(1)        : "; T t2(1);
  std::cout << "T t3 = 1       : "; T t3 = 1;
  std::cout << "T t4 = T(1)    : "; T t4 = T(1);
  std::cout << "T t5(1, 2)     : "; T t5(1, 2);
  std::cout << "T t6 = T(1, 2) : "; T t6 = T(1, 2);
  std::cout << "T t7; t7 = 1   : "; T t7; t7 = 1;
  std::cout << "T t8; t8 = T(1): "; T t8; t8 = T(1);
  std::cout << "T t9(t8)       : "; T t9(t8);
  std::cout << "T t10 = 'a'    : "; T t10 = 'a';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за наглядное приложение.

Answer (score 4):

В тех случаях, когда нужно проинициализировать новый объект существующим (т.е. сделать точную копию объекта), используется конструктор копирования. Полагаю, что основной "плюс" такого конструктора как раз в том, что работает быстрее, чем `operator=`, т.к. позволяет проиницализировать данные объекта во время их конструирования. Еще немаловажный момент: если в процессе инициализации нового объекта будет выброшено исключение, например `bad_alloc`, то некорректный объект создан не будет (впрочем, то же самое касается любого конструктора).

Стандартное применение: класс объектов, размещаемых в `std::vector<>`, должен поддерживать конструктор копирования.