# Объясните почему не вызывается явный конструктор, а конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

Код вызываемый с моей стороны

```
Window  window = Window(L"Hello Word", 800, 600);
```

Вызывается конструктор копирования, по факту должен быть был вызван явный конструктор

Вот заголовочный файл

```
struct WindowClass final {
public:
    WindowClass(const std::wstring& name, ::WNDPROC procedure = ::DefWindowProcW);
    ~WindowClass();
    WindowClass(const WindowClass&)            = delete;
    WindowClass& operator=(const WindowClass&) = delete;

    auto GetName() const noexcept->const std::wstring&;

private:
    std::wstring m_Name;

};

struct IWindow {
public:
    IWindow()                          = default;
    IWindow(const IWindow&)            = delete;
    IWindow& operator=(const IWindow&) = delete;

    virtual ~IWindow();
    auto IsClosed() const   noexcept->bool;
    virtual auto OnClose()  noexcept->IWindow& = 0;

    auto GetWidth()  const  noexcept->uint32_t;
    auto GetHeight() const  noexcept->uint32_t;

private:
    virtual auto IsClosedImpl()  const noexcept->bool     = 0;
    virtual auto GetWidthImpl()  const noexcept->uint32_t = 0;
    virtual auto GetHeightImpl() const noexcept->uint32_t = 0;

};

class Window : public IWindow {
private:
    HWND      m_hWnd    = nullptr;
    bool      m_IsClose = false;
    uint32_t  m_Width   = 0;
    uint32_t  m_Height  = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<WindowClass> m_WindowClass;

public:
    Window(const std::wstring& tittle, uint32_t width, uint32_t height);
    ~Window();

    auto GetHWND() const noexcept-> HWND;
    auto OnClose()  noexcept->IWindow&  override;
private:
    auto IsClosedImpl()  const noexcept->bool     override;
    auto GetWidthImpl()  const noexcept->uint32_t override;
    auto GetHeightImpl() const noexcept->uint32_t override;

};
```

Visual Studio 2017 выдает такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой статье можно проверить, что при моем способе должен быть быть вызван конструктор инициализации
[Конструктор копирования c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148207/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-c)

Comment: Код должен быть включён в вопрос не в виде картинки, а в виде текста. Вам система не дала вставить картинку именно для этого.

Comment: Вот прикрепил, я новичёк пока не освоился))

Comment: Давайте повторюсь: Код должен быть включён в вопрос не в виде картинки, а в виде **текста**.

Comment: Подправил так вот пойдет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы вы написали

```
Window window(....);
```

то вызывался бы обычный конструктор, но вы пытаетесь создать временный объект и им инициализировать переменную - соответственно, копируете временный объект в вашу переменную...

Впрочем, современный C++ обходится без копирования в данном случае. Вернее, так - он обходится без конструктора копирования, но требует его наличия - концептуально...

Например -

```
class Test
{
    Test(const Test&) { cout << "Test::Test(const Test&)\n"; }

public:
    Test() { cout << "Test::Test()\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t = Test();
}
```

Этот код не скомпилируется из-за отсутствия доступа к конструктору копирования. Но если его перенести в раздел `public` - все скомпилируется, но вызван он так и не будет.

Насколько я помню, с стандарта С++17 копирующий конструктор уже не требуется в таких ситуациях в принципе. Но тут пусть меня поправят гуру, я могу и ошибаться...

Comment: Напишите `Window window(L"Hello Word", 800, 600);` - зачем вам копирование?

Comment: В этом как раз и вопроc  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s16xw1a8.aspx#explicitly_invoking_constructors к явно вызываемым конструкторам промотайте

Comment: Запутали окончательно... Что именно вам непонятно? Вы, кстати, неверно задали вопрос - потому что копирующий конструктор не вызывается реально, но проверяется его наличие...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148207/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-c Дайте копилятору первый ответ, вы увидите что должен вызваться конструктор иницализации

Comment: То есть по факту вызывается конструктор иницализации, но если конструкор копирования удален, то выдается ошибка. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, именно так. Я сейчас немного подчитал :) - до С++17 в таких случаях создавался концептуальный временный объект (т.е. требовалось наличие конструктора копирования), начиная с С++17 он не нужен. Но, похоже, VC++ 2017 в этом все еще не дотягивает до стандарта С++17.

Comment: Вот цитата из "Шаблонов С++" Вандевурда - *В случае C++17 pr-значение само по себе не создает временный объект. Вместо этого оно инициализирует объект, определяемый контекстом. ... Никакие операции копирования или перемещения [при этом] не рассматриваются (и это не оптимизация, а гарантия языка)*.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 3):

"По факту" в этом случае должен быть вызван явный конструктор только в С++17, где появилось *guaranteed copy elision*.

В более ранних версиях языка С++ в этом случае вы выполняете именно инициализацию при помощи *конструктора копирования*, которая может быть (а может и не быть) оптимизирована компилятором до вызова явного конструктора.

Очевидно, вы используете компилятор, который не подчиняется требованиям C++17.